# Retaining px dimension when export to a PNG file. Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png

In Adobe Illustrator I have an Icon that has dimensions of 200px by 200px. When I export it to a PNG file though,the PNG file is 834px by 834px. Any suggestions to keep the icon at 200 by 200 pixels?

Comment: what export resolution are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you did not check the *Use Artboards* option on the export window, Illustrator defaults to **exporting everything in your workspace**.

But I would recommend using the *File > Save for Web...* command, instead.

*Save for web* has the advantage of allowing you more control over the output. For example, you can even preview how things are going to be rendered and the final file size *before* exporting it. It also automatically crops to artboard size, so you don't have to worry about any overlapping objects.

Answer (score 4):

For those who still have the problem with odd number like me. Such as 67, 143 ,or others. It will convert to 68 or 144. (for me)

Here steps for you to fix :

- Make sure Artboard is the same size with Background. (Size that you want it to be)
- Select all objects
- in transform X or Y should have “.5” , Cut it out
- open Artboard minus X or Y with .5 (Position that you cut it out in transform)
- Then export with normal default | Done

Comment: Moving the artboard to a whole number position on both the X and Y axis fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. I was already doing what all the other solutions suggested ("Save for Web" vs "Export", tick "Use Artboard", etc). Manually adjusting the Artboard size to the nearest (smaller) whole number resulted in a larger, all-inclusive/uncropped PNG (go figure).

Answer (score 1):

File > Document Setup > Units > Pixels

(the following items can be found in toolbar when Artboard tool is selected)
[image]

1) Select Artboard, with Move/Copy Artwork button Active

2) Set Reference Point to upper Left Corner

3) Set X: 0 px, Y: 0 px

File > Export > Export for Screens

Formats: > set to desired px size

Answer (score 0):

While exporting the PNG Image of 200Pixels and Artboard of 834 Pixels select the Use Artboard Icon in Export palette as shown in [this Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLPCUeMbHqI).